# Can a stochastic process have stationary increments which are not independent increments?

Tags: stochastic-processes, levy-processes

I can see that increments could be independent but not stationary, but can't think of an example going in the other direction, i.e., stationary but dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z$ be standard normal and consider the process $X_t = tZ$.

---

There are other, much less trivial, examples (e.g. fractional Brownian motion with $H \neq 1/2$) but this one is fairly immediate to see both properties (stationary but not independent increments)

Comment: I see the stationary increments property but it is not clear to me why the increments are dependent.

Comment: @StephenFratini One way we may see this is that $$P(X_1-X_0 > 0, X_3-X_2 < 0) = P(Z>0, Z<0) = 0$$ $$P(X_1-X_0>0)P(X_3-X_2<0) = P(Z>0)P(Z<0) = \frac{1}{4}$$ so the increments $X_1-X_0, X_3-X_2$ aren't independent.  However, we can go even further:
 Increments of the process $X_t$ are related by $X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} = \frac{t_1-t_0}{s_1-s_0}(X_{s_1}-X_{s_0})$, so any two intervals are related deterministically.